# Contract event listener is not firing when running hardhat tests with ethers js

Tags: hardhat, ethers.js

Here is a very small repo to show the issue: https://github.com/adamdry/ethers-event-issue

But I'll explain it here too. This is my contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED;
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract ContractA {

    event TokensMinted(uint amount);

    function mint(uint amount) public {
        emit TokensMinted(amount);
    }

}
```

And this is my test code:

```
import * as chai from 'chai'
import { BigNumber, ContractTransaction } from 'ethers'
import { ethers } from 'hardhat'
import { ContractA, ContractAFactory } from '../typechain'

const expect = chai.expect

describe("Example test", function () {
    it("should fire the event", async function () {
        const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const contractAFactory = (await ethers.getContractFactory(
            'ContractA',
            owner,
        )) as ContractAFactory

        const contractA: ContractA = await contractAFactory.deploy()

        contractA.on('TokensMinted', (amount: BigNumber) => {
            // THIS LINE NEVER GETS HIT
            console.log('###########')
        })

        const contractTx: ContractTransaction = await contractA.mint(123)
        const contractReceipt: ContractReceipt = await contractTx.wait()

        for (const event of contractReceipt.events!) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
        }
    });
});
```

I was expecting the `###########` to get printed to the console however it doesn't so the listener function isn't being executed for some reason.

If I dig into the ContractReceipt the correct event data is there:

```json
{
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockNumber": 2,
  "transactionHash": "0x55d118548c8200e5e6c19759d9aab56cb2e6a274186a92643de776d617d51e1a",
  "address": "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3",
  "topics": [
    "0x772f66a00a405709c30e7f18feadcc8f123b20c09c7260165d3eec36c9f21372"
  ],
  "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b",
  "logIndex": 0,
  "blockHash": "0x808e6949118509b5a9e482e84cf47921a2fcffbcd943ebbd8ce4f6671469ee01",
  "args": [
    {
      "type": "BigNumber",
      "hex": "0x7b"
    }
  ],
  "event": "TokensMinted",
  "eventSignature": "TokensMinted(uint256)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, default polling interval in an ethers provider is 4 seconds. By the time it polls, your `it('', async function () {})` has finished execution, and garbage collector might even clear the local variables `contract` immediately after it finishes.

A simple solution could be to add a wait of 4 seconds or higher, v

```
  ...

  for (const event of contractReceipt.events!) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
  }

  // waits for 5 sec
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000));
});
```

You can also reduce the polling interval, however, the minimum value is 1 msec.

```
contractA.provider.pollingInterval = 1;
```